# Deploying Games to firefox OS

Tags: html, firefox-os

Im actually facing a problem on submitting an app to Firefox OS marketplace.Recently i developed an HTML5 game using construct 2 and tested it on the Simulator using App manager, and submitted the app on the firefos marketplace.It passed all validation checks, however the reviewer said game stops loading on Firefox OS 1.1,so i was rejected!
Now i have then tested it on Simulator for 1.1, and the game stops loading.
So the problem is with OS 1.1 , other than that the game works fine, esp with OS 2.0

Now , can i submit the game only for versions above 1.1??
I dont want the app to run on 1.1, i just want to submit it for versions higher versions.

Is it possible?? any help??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually mostly reviewers will be using Firefox OS 1.1 to test the application because it is widely used.

If you have written the working app you can mention the simulator in which you have tested or can tell the device OS version you have used. So other reviewers will know and wont reject the app.

PS:- Try to use the target development environment as Firefox 2.0 in mid of 2015 and as of now Firefox 1.3 and above as many people have 1.1 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Some apps state in their descriptions the minimum version required for it to work. For example: https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/recorder and https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/copy-paste-keyboard.